# Storing a value and duplicating a field onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a field where a user can input there email address, however i also have a button underneath that field that says 'Add more', I am struggling to find a way to store the email value and have the user input another email, I am using React hooks for this process, for instance I understand that i would need to store the value of the email inside a

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState=();
```

below is my code relating to the problem

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <TextField
      className={classes.field}
      id="contactEmails"
      name="contactEmails"
      label="Contact Email(s)"
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="lname"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 250
      }}
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Button className={classes.addButton} variant='contained' color='primary'> Add Another Email</Button>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wu-gjwj1

Comment: @ChrisG this works fine however, when logging the values of emails they will permanently be set to an empty string?

Comment: You need to turn your TextFields into controlled inputs. I updated the sandbox.

Comment: @ChrisG thankyou this seems to do the trick, if you could for my benefit could you explain the onChange function please?

Comment: Sure; I have an array of emails in my state, but I only need to update a single one. Therefore the function uses `map()` to essentially create a copy of the email array, however in the case of the currently edited one, i.e. `i === j`, I use the value of the text field instead (which I grab using `event.target.value`).

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to have *one* stateful `email` but rather `emails` (an array of emails):

```
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([]);
```

To then  add an email, take the previous emails and add one:

```
  setEmails([...emails, "new.email@example.com"]);
```

Replacing an email works the same way:

```
  setEmails(emails.map(prev => prev === "previous@example.com" ? "new@example.com" : prev));
```

Now you have to render all those emails too, for that you can map the array of emails into an array of components and return that from your component:

```
   return emails.map(email => <p> {email} </p>);
```

You might want to have a look at `useReducer` for this instead though, that'll be far more elegant...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another option already working: https://jsfiddle.net/hpuey7zn/

Explanation:

- In the state you store the current `input` value (see function `handleChange`) and an array of `emails`
- `onClick` button adds the current email to the array if it is not included (see `handleClick`).

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        input: '',
        emails: []
    }
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
    }

    handleClick = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const { emails, input } = this.state;
            if (!emails.includes(input))
                this.setState({ emails: [...emails, input]});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    name="email" label="email" type="email"
                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                />
                <button onClick={ev => { this.handleClick(ev)}}>
                    Add Another Email
                </button>
                <div>EMAILS:</div>
                <ul>{this.state.emails.map(email => <li>{email}</li>)}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

---

And here you have a version with hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([]);

  return (
      <div>
          <input name="email" label="email" type="email"
              onChange={ ev => {setInput(ev.target.value)} }
          />
          <button onClick={ev => {
              if (!emails.includes(input)) setEmails([...emails, input])
          }}>
              Add Another Email
          </button>
          <div>EMAILS:</div>
          <ul>{emails.map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}</ul>
      </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement) ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```